# How to solve this probability problem analytically (instead of using simulation)? Probability of winning prize

Tags: probability, distributions

I ran across a probability problem as follows:

In a certain prize give away, to win a prize, you must spell the word "WIN". The tickets are printed so that 70% of them have a "W", 20% have an "I", and 10% have an "N". If you purchase 10 tickets, what is the probability that you will win the prize?

I have an estimate of 0.6 (if rounding to one decimal place) through simulation, but I don't know **how to solve this problem analytically** and **what probability distribution should be used**.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution
Each ticket gives you a W, I, or N with probability .7, .2, and .1. What's the probability that 10 tickets contains at least one of each?

Comment: Thank you @assumednormal. My struggle with using multinomial distribution directly lies in the large amount of possible combinations for $n_{W}$, $n_{I}$, and $n_{N}$ for fully describing "10 tickets contains at least one of each". Would you mind telling me a bit more about the multinomial-based solution? Thanks!

Comment: You can view all these combinations on [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Expand+%28%287+W+%2B+2+J+%2B+N%29%2F10%29%5E10+-+%28%287+W+%2B+2+J%29%2F10%29%5E10+-+%28%287+W+%2B++N%29%2F10%29%5E10+-+%28%28+2+J+%2B+N%29%2F10%29%5E10+%2B+%287W%2F10%29%5E10+%2B+%282J%2F10%29%5E10+%2B+%28N%2F10%29%5E10). Then, to obtain the probability, just set all the variables to $1$ (redo the calculation with `/. {W->1,J->1,N->1}` appended). This sort of calculation can be instructive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's find the case we couldn't *WIN*. Call the individual probabilities as $p_w,p_i,p_n$, and call it $k$ trials:
$$P(\text{WI})=(1-p_n)^{k},
P(\text{WN})=(1-p_i)^{k},
P(\text{NI})=(1-p_w)^{k}$$
$$P(\text{W})=p_w^{k},
P(\text{N})=p_n^{k},
P(\text{I})=p_i^{k}$$

Via [Inclusion-Exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) Principle:

$P(\text{WIN})=1-(P(\text{WI})+P(\text{WN})+P(\text{NI}) - P(\text{W})-P(\text{N})-P(\text{I}))\approx 0.572$